# How do I delete a column in a dataframe that has no title but contains a list of numbers from 1-39?

Tags: r

I have a data frame that has a list of species and sites that I'd like to compute for some analysis using beta.pair: Incidence-based pair-wise dissimilarities. In betapart: Partitioning Beta Diversity into Turnover and Nestedness Components. However, there is a first column (without heading) but contains numbers from 1-39 that I would like to remove so that the function can read the presence-absence data.

The data frame looks something like this:

[image]

Comment: Are you wanting to remove the column, `cluster_number`, from your example?

Comment: Yes, I would like to remove this column. I am trying to run this in rstudio but the error pops up..> betapart::beta.pair(nfi_nonTree_spCom, index.family = "sorensen")
Error in betapart.core(x) : 
  The table contains values other than 0 and 1: data should be presence/absence.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like an [index column](https://www.statology.org/drop-index-pandas/). It should not affect the analyses you are trying to do.
There are several uses for the index column. For instance, you can use the index for explicitly analyzing or subsetting your data.

You can check to see if that is an index column or not by looking at the shape of the data.

If this is pandas dataframe, you could try

`df.shape`

and it should show the actual dimensions of the data (without the index included). So for the example table you provided, the result would be - (21, 7).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remove a single column by setting the entire column to `NULL`

```
nfi_nonTree_spCom$cluster_number <- NULL
```

For a small example to show this,

```
colnames(mtcars)
#  [1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear" "carb"

# Remove column
mtcars$mpg <- NULL

colnames(mtcars)
#  [1] "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear" "carb"
```

We've removed the `mpg` column so notice that the results of the column names function returns a list without the `mpg` column, which was the first in the list.